# Failed Deployment in App Engine Google Cloud

Tags: express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-appengine-node

I am deploying my nodejs application in google cloud app engine but it is giving error 
**This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. 
This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.** -- when making request.

I had also saw some stackoverflow answers, but they didn't worked for me.

my **app.yaml** have this config

***runtime: nodejs10***

Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following to your app.yaml:

```
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

And then implement a handler that will catch all warmup requests, so that your application doesn't get the full load. The full explanation is given [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests). Another detailed post about this topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509022/how-solve-high-latency-in-app-engine-caused-by-this-request-caused-a-new-proces).

Additionally you can also add automatic scaling options. You can play a bit with those to find the optimum for your application. Especially the latency related variables are important. Good to note that they can be set in a standard GAE environment.

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
```

More scaling options can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements).

Comment: Thats works. But when we get ideal for some time then the first request will be load request and it will give same error, According to the doc. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests


Is there any way to handle it

Answer (score 1):

The "request caused a new process to be started" notification usually occurred when there is no warm up request present in your application.

Can you try to implement a health check handler that only returns a ready status when the application is warmed up. This will allow your service to not receive traffic until it is ready.

> Warning: Legacy health checks using the /_ah/health path are now
>   deprecated, and you should migrate to use split health checks.

Here you can find [Split health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#updated_health_checks) for Nodejs

**Liveness checks**

> Liveness checks confirm that the VM and the Docker container are
>   running. Instances that are deemed unhealthy are restarted.

```
  path: "/liveness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
```

**Readiness checks**

> Readiness checks confirm that an instance can accept incoming
>   requests. Instances that don't pass the readiness check are not added
>   to the pool of available instances.

```
  path: "/readiness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

## Edit

For App Engine Standard, which doesn't afford you that flexibility, hardware and software failures that cause early termination or frequent restarts can occur without prior warning. [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?place=forum/google-appengine-python&hl=EL&nomobile=true#!topic/google-appengine/IWNzceG4FxY)

> App Engine attempts to keep manual and basic scaling instances running
>   indefinitely. However, at this time there is no guaranteed uptime for
>   manual and basic scaling instances. Hardware and software failures
>   that cause early termination or frequent restarts can occur without
>   prior warning and can take considerable time to resolve; thus, you
>   should construct your application in a way that tolerates these
>   failures.
>
> Here are some good strategies for avoiding downtime due to instance
>   restarts:
>
> Reduce the amount of time it takes for your instances restart or for
>   new ones to start.
>
> For long-running computations, periodically create
>   checkpoints so that you can resume from that state.
>
> Your app should be "stateless" so that nothing is stored on the instance.
>
> Use queues for performing asynchronous task execution.
>
> If you configure your instances to manual scaling: Use load balancing across > multiple instances. Configure more instances than required to handle normal
>   traffic. Write fall-back logic that uses cached results when a manual
>   scaling instance is unavailable.

[Instance Uptime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed#instance_uptime)

Comment: This seems a good idea. But I am I am using my app in standard environment. Health check will restart the server. This means my instance in standard environment  will never go down. I this this will behave as flex environment. Correct me if I am wrong